# Is there any way to change default selectManager state name of "-State-" to Default in grapesjs?

Tags: reactjs, grapesjs

I've integrated grapesjs with React. Now I want to change the default selector manager states name to "Default". I've added a states in the selector manager like

```
 states: [{ name: 'Default' },{ name: 'hover' }, { name: 'active' }, { name: 'nth-of-type(2n)' }],
```

in setupEditor. How can I change the "-States-" to "Default" label

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if grapesjs has a bug on it, but i just could change the strings with a plugin, so, following the https://github.com/artf/grapesjs-cli repo, i was abble to change the localization of Grapesjs, as the string you're asked.

In default plugin code, i put it:

```
var I18nManager = editor.I18n;
I18nManager.addMessages({ en: { selectorManager: { emptyState: "Default" } } })
```

Check:
[image]